# Reading a pdf file using python

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, pdfminer

I have a pdf form that has been converted into normal pdf document(using print2pdf software) . I intend to extract the data from the same , is there any way of doing so ?

I am currently using pdfminer , but it tends not extract the data entered by the user , but extracts all other data.

`pdf2txt.py PDFFormconvertedintoPDF.pdf`

is there any alternative approach which would help me achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Pdftotext or pyPDF.  These tools are also pretty widely used and there are stackoverflow questions about them as well